# Missing Node Inputs

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I've never really used nodes before so I'm following tutorials to learn them and for some reason my "Mesh To Volume Node" looks like this
[image]

when it should look like this

[image]

Does anybody know what's going on? I'm new to 3d modeling and just updated to blender 4.0

Comment: Hello, the best way to follow a tutorial if you're beginning is to try and install / use the same version that the tutor is using, because the interface changes pretty much every version especially regarding nodes

Comment: Okay I see thanks for the help!